# Unzip a file that has a folder with special character encoding in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, special-characters, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file I have downloaded with R. I can unzip the file in Windows (for instance, using WiwRAR) with no problem, but when trying to do it using R, I get the following error:

```
> unzip("data/raw/censo_2010.zip", exdir="data/raw")
Error in unzip("data/raw/censo_2010.zip", exdir = "data/raw") : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<87><c6>o '
```

The file was downloaded using this:

```
> download.file("https://download.inep.gov.br/microdados/microdados_censo_da_educacao_superior_2010.zip",
                "data/raw/censo_2010.zip")
```

I have tried listing the contents of the .zip file in R and the beggining of the result is this:

```
Name
1
Microdados do Censo da Educa\x87\xc6o Superior 2010/
2
Microdados do Censo da Educa\x87\xc6o Superior 2010/Anexos/
3
Microdados do Censo da Educa\x87\xc6o Superior 2010/Anexos/ANEXO I - Dicion\xa0rio de Dados/
4
Microdados do Censo da Educa\x87\xc6o Superior 2010/Anexos/ANEXO I - Dicion\xa0rio de Dados/dicion\xa0rio_dados_educa\x87\xc6o_superior.xlsx
...
```

I believe unzip in R is having trouble with the special characters in Portuguese (the output in line 1 is supposed to be "Microdados do Censo da Educa**çã**o Superior 2010/"). I cannot alter the original .zip file since I am trying to write a reproducible R script and the .zip file is supplied from the government.

How can I unzip this file in R?

Comment: According to the `unzip` documentation you can get round this by including the option `unzip = "unzip"` in the `unzip(...)` statement

Comment: @AndrewGustar but doesn't that require the existence of `unzip` version 6 or later?  I wonder whether the OP could use `unzip = 'WinRAR'` successfully

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, certainly worth a try!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Trying `unzip = "WinRAR"` did not work, and gave out this `Warning message:
In system2(unzip, args, stdout = NULL, stderr = NULL, invisible = TRUE) :
  '"WinRAR"' not found`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you, using `unzip = "unzip"` seemed to work well enough, but the special characters were switched to bullet point-like dots. That should be easy enough to correct manually, but would there be any option to keep the original special characters?

Comment: @GabrielBanaggia Not sure - there doesn't seem to be a way to pass options to the end unzip utility. Another option worth trying might be the R `zip` package. There is a `zip::unzip` function which might be more sophisticated than the base version.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Educa\x87\xc6o'.encode('latin1').decode('cp850')` returns `'Educação'`…

Comment: `Error in download.file(  ...url...",  : 
  cannot open URL `  Warning: `'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates'`